# How to extract data into a data frame from several lists

Tags: r, list

I have a dataset, from which I created subsets using different thresholds of a variable called VAR, here is how I did it:

```
X <- seq(from=3.5, to=5, by=0.1)
for (i in X) {
  assign(paste("gev",i), gev.fit(-mydata[(mydata$VAR < i), 6]))
}
```

So now I have several lists named gev 3.5, gev 3.6 and so on.
I want to extract the three parameter estimates from all the lists (e.g. `gev 3.5`[[7]]) and put them into a data frame.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using `assign` with dynamic object names. It makes it very hard to use these objects later on in your script.

Instead, I suggest you create a list and assign the results to your list. One issue you will face is that lists don't like indices with decimal places, i.e. it will not distinguish between `3.5` and `3.6`. That's why I'm using integers as indices.

I'm also extracting the 7th element of each `gev.fit` object straight away, instead of later. If you need the entire object first, you can extract the 7th element of each list using an `apply` function.

```
X = seq(from=3.5, to=5, by=0.1)

gevlist <- list()
for (i in seq_along(X)) {
  max_var <- X[i]
  gevlist[[i]] <- gev.fit(-mydata[(mydata$VAR < max_var), 6])[[7]]
}

gev.models <- data.frame(X = X, models = gevlist)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. I did try it but R gives this error message: Error in optim(init, gev.lik, hessian = TRUE, method = method, control = list(maxit = maxit,  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim Also I am wondering what role max_var has in your code, the rest I understand. Sorry if I ask basic questions,

Comment: Ah, apologies, the `max_var` variable was supposed to replace `i`, since `i` is only an integer index in my version. I edited my answer to correct it. The error you report seems to be caused by something internal to `gev.fit`, which I don't know enough about to help you with - perhaps my edit already fixes the error?

Comment: Ok, so now I have an even more basic issue:) This is how my list looks like right now. I would like to have such a dataframe where mu, szig, and kszi are columns using the gevlist data
[[1]]
[1] -3.3354997  0.2301914  1.0979842

[[2]]
[1] -3.3275922  0.2505644  0.8881143

[[3]]
[1] -3.3743078  0.3318792  0.4635529
[[4]]
...

For each row I want to calculate a new value 1-exp(-(1+kszi*((0-mu)/szig))^(-1/kszi))

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for this issue.

Comment: @AttilaBorsos If my answer solved your question, can you mark it as solved?